# How to derive effective transconductance versus oscillation amplitude in a oscillator?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, oscillator, oscillation, transconductance

In the page below in [the lecture](https://picture.iczhiku.com/resource/eetop/wyKtWWZPjSpwECNx.pdf) note shows a plot of effective transconductance versus oscillation amplitude.

How is it derived? 
 Or is there any source to derive effective transconductance versus oscillation amplitude curve like that?

[image]

Comment: The picture shows a square voltage, and the definition says "*the ratio between the* **fundamental** *harmonic [...] and the harmonic [...]*". Does it ring any bell?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen a square wave includes many sine waveforms but I don't know what to proceed.

Comment: If the fundamental has amplitude 1, and the 3rd harmonic is 1/3, what is the ratio? What about the 5th harmonic? The 7th, etc? And if you collate these into a graph you get the dotted line, whose formula is very visible. The solid line is due to the OTA's physical limitations (also see how a linear graph looks like for an opamp's open loop response).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I think I start to get it. And now read the explaination they said make more sense.